# How to prove $\|A^+\|_2\leq\|A^{-1}_1\|_2$ in the question?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the $m×n$ matrix $A$ has the form $A=\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 \\
A_2
\end{pmatrix}$ where $ A_1$ is a nonsingular matrix of dimension $n×n$ and $A_2$ is an arbitrary matrix of dimension $(m-n)×n$. Prove that $\|A^+\|_2\leq\|A^{-1}_1\|_2$.

My idea of this problem:
In order to calculate the 2-norm, I calculate the eigenvalues of $(A^+)^*A^+$ and $(A^{-1}_1)^*A^{-1}_1$(which are $(AA^*)^{-1}$ and $(A_1A_1^*)^{-1}$ after simplifying). Now I do not know how to compare their eigenvalues.

Comment: If $A_1$ is $n \times n$ and $A_2$ is $(m-n) \times n$ then would not A be $m \times 2n$ the way you have defined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns of $A$ are independent,

$A^+=(A_1^*A_1+A_2^*A_2)^{-1}[A_1^*,A_2^*]$ and, therefore

$A^+{A^+}^*=(A_1^*A_1+A_2^*A_2)^{-1}$.

Moreover $A_1^{-1}{A_1^{-1}}^*=(A_1^*A_1)^{-1}$.

Since $0_n<A_1^*A_1\leq A_1^*A_1+A_2^*A_2$,

$\lambda_{min}(A_1^*A_1)\leq \lambda_{min}(A_1^*A_1+A_2^*A_2)$ and

$\lambda_{max}((A_1^*A_1)^{-1})\geq \lambda_{max}((A_1^*A_1+A_2^*A_2)^{-1})$ and we are done.

Comment: why $A^+{A^+}^*=(A_1^*A_1+A_2^*A_2)^{-1}$?

Comment: Write the product.